# Apache ActiveMQ 5.10 startup issue

Tags: activemq-classic

I downloaded Activemq_5.10 and configured using the command "activemq start" from the bin folder.

It is not moving after the last line and is not properly started, because of which the console is not up.

Extract of the log is:

```
| INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
| INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
| INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
| INFO  | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed | /api | main
```

Comment: Are You using OpenJDK ?

Comment: @WBAR: I am using the regular jdk_1.7.0_25. I also tried with ActiveMQ 8 and 9. I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 2):

That is the last line logged, ActiveMQ should be started, eg when I do on ActiveMQ 5.10.0

```
bin/activemq console
```

I see

 `INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (localhost, ID:davsclaus.air-62275-1403850867605-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/apache-activemq-5.10.0/data/kahadb only has 74949 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 74949 mb
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 INFO | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed`

And I can see the old web console at

```
http://localhost:8161/
```

And I can connect to the broker remotely using hawtio as documented here:

- http://sensatic.net/activemq/activemq-and-hawtio.html

So I think your ActiveMQ is running as expected.

Comment: I just checked the URL after starting activemq. I can see now. When I tested back, I did not restart the computer after changes or I dont know why it was not working. Anyhow, thanks for your comments.